# Haskell function reversing a list and inserting a new element into it

Tags: haskell

I have been working on a Haskell function which is suppose to take a list as well as a value. It should reverse the list and then append the value to the front.

I've tried making separate reverse and insert function and calling one on the other but I have failed to find a way to make it work. Here is what I have so far:

Reverse Function:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' [] = []  
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Insert Function:

```
insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]   
insert x [] = [x]
insert x (y:ys)
  | x > y     = y : insert x ys
  | otherwise = x : y : ys
```

Should I should call one of these functions on the other? If so how would I go about doing that? Or if I should just make one function? I've tinkered with this quite a bit and can't seem to get either way to work.

Thank you for any and all help as I am still a beginner and learning the language!

Comment: What precisely is your question?

Comment: I apologize for not adding that part in there as it may help if you all know what the actual question was! Basically what I want to know is if I should call one of these functions on the other or if I should just make one function? I've tinkered with this quite a bit and can't seem to get either way to work.

Comment: @TomMoore I suggest you edit your post to add the question to it. (And while you are at it, a less generic title would also help.)

Comment: You want to insert the value to the front of the reversed list, right?

Comment: Correct @mnoronha

Comment: I have the feeling there may be some miscommunication. Tom Moore, can you please show several examples of arguments to your desired function and the corresponding results?

Comment: Examples:

    Prelude> reverseAndInsert 2 [3,4,5]
        Result: [2,5,4,3]

    Prelude> reverseAndInsert 7[8,9,10]
        Result: [7,10,9,8]

Comment: @TomMoore This should be the behavior you observe based on my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reverse'` function works as expected, so we can use it to reverse the list that is passed to our function (note that it's use is identical to, though less efficient than, than `reverse` from `Prelude`). The `insert` function you've written is less useful here because we want to insert our value to the front of the front of the list, not after the first value that is less than it.

We'll thus apply your `reverse'` function to the list and cons the input value to the front of what gets returned.

```
reverseAndInsert :: a -> [a] -> [a]
reverseAndInsert x xs = x : reverse' xs
```

Comment: `reverse'` is technically not identical to `reverse` from Prelude because it's O(n^2) rather than O(n).  That difference can matter.

Comment: @Carl It's *use* is the same, but I've modified the statement.